# How to filter a ManyToMany query in a class based view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have the following models:

```
class List(models.Model):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Participant, through='ParticipantThroughModel', blank=True)

class ParticipantThroughModel(models.Model):
    participantlist = models.ForeignKey(List, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    participants = models.ForeignKey(Participant, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_responsible_person = models.BooleanField()

class Participant(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And I have the following view:

```
class ListDetail(DetailView):
    model = List
    template_name = 'participantlists/participantlist_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'participantlist
```

In my template, I can display all the `Participant` via:

```
{% for obj in participantlist.participantthroughmodel_set.all %}
{{ obj.participants }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, if I want to filter this to display both this code with all `participants` and another `for` loop showing only `participants` with `is_responsible_person = True` how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the queryset in the view, by overriding the [**`get_context_data(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data):

```
class ListDetail(DetailView):
    model = List
    template_name = 'participantlists/participantlist_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'participantlist'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        result = super().get_context_data()
        result.update(
            participants=self.object.participantthroughmodel_set.filter(is_responsible_person=True)
        )
        return result
```

in the template, you then can iterate over `participants`:

```
{% for obj in participants %}
    {{ obj.participants }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, if I also wanted to pass the unfiltered original `participantlist` how could I update this?

Comment: @alias51: you just add an extra item to the `result` (this is a simple dictionary).

Comment: @alias51 `participantlist` is still in your context, next to `participants` (`result['participantlist']` is populated by the call to `super().get_context_data()`)